# Why do we take only the positive square roots when solving trig functions?

Tags: trigonometry

I was trying to solve the problem:

If $\tan^2 x=1-a^2$, then prove that $\sec x + \tan^3 x   \ \csc  x=(2-a^2)^{3/2}$

Now, there are a lot of clever ways to do this problem, but I did it by

$$\tan^2 x=1-a^2$$
$$\tan x=\pm\sqrt{1-a^2}$$

Similarly,
$$\sec x=\pm\sqrt{2-a^2}$$
And
$$\csc  x=\pm\sqrt\frac{1-a^2}{2-a^2}$$
But, substituting all of these pluses and minuses into the eqn  becomes complicated,so I see the answer.
But there, they dont take the $\pm$ at all.

So, this is my question. Why, in trig functions, can you sometimes omit the $\pm$?

Comment: In general, you cannot.  However, the trigonometric ratios are either positive or negative in certain quadrants, and many questions use that to choose between positive or negative.

Comment: So, should I always assume trig functions to lie in the 1st quadrant?

Comment: Not unless it is stated.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to simplify the left hand side before replacing the actual values

$$\sec x +\tan^3x\csc x=\dfrac1{\cos x}+\dfrac{\sin^2x}{\cos^3x}=\dfrac1{\cos^3x}$$

Now $\sec x=\pm\sqrt{1+\tan^2x}$  according as $\sec x>0$ or $<0$

We should clearly state : we have assumed $\sec x>0$